# Move from sortable to sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there any way for me to allow a user to drag a div which I've put in a sortable list (`I used jquery ui's $.sortable()` function), into a different sortable list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [`connectWith`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-connectWith) option for sortables.

Essentially, if you only want `#DivA` to be able to drag elements to `#DivB` your sortables would be:

```
$('#DivA').sortable({connectWith: ['#DivB']});
$('#DivB').sortable();
```

If you want to be able to exchange items between the two you have to set the relationship both ways:

```
$('#DivA').sortable({connectWith: ['#DivB']});
$('#DivB').sortable({connectWith: ['#DivA']});
```